# Create a single pdf from multiple text, images or pdf files

Tags: files, pdf, image-processing, merge

I have a bunch of text files, images and pdf files which I want to convert into a single pdf file. How do I do it?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/302927/147044

Comment: Well, you can do `convert image1.jpg image2.png text.txt PDFfile.pdf outputFileName.pdf`. It worked for me, but the problem is it converts the text.txt file into an image, so you can't highlight the text in the resulting pdf.

Comment: @Alaa you should post this as an answer rather than a comment. Simple, concise and on the money.

Comment: gscan2pdf Is a GUI version also in case the command 'convert' fails and worked for me. (from ifoss.com): Once gscan2pdf is opened, you can select all the required files in it by clicking on the Open Files. By default  it is arranged in alphabetical order but you can drag and drop to reorder the images as per your choice. then click on the Save icon to save the files to PDF. if you just want a PDF file, hit the save . Since by default the output file is PDF, you don’t need to bother a lot here. Just choose where to save the converted file.
Save the converted images to pdf, That’s it.

Comment: See also [How to generate a PDF from a series of images?](https://superuser.com/questions/687849) on superuser.

Comment: @AlaaAli, you can take your resulting PDF and make it searchable again using my `pdf2searchablepdf` tool I wrote, [which I describe here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385947/327339). It's a wrapper around the `tesseract` OCR engine.

Comment: [Here is an excellent text to PDF solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20129300/4561887)

Answer (score 213):

If you're willing to use a terminal, you can use ImageMagick.  Install it with

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

then you can do:

```
convert image1.jpg image2.png text.txt PDFfile.pdf outputFileName.pdf
```

or as another example:

```
convert *.jpg outputJpgFiles.pdf
```

It worked for me, but the problem is it converts the `text.txt` file into an image, so you can't highlight the text in the resulting pdf.

Comment: ImageMagic `convert` reduces quality and increases size in my experience. Try `pdftk`. But not sure how you add images there.

Comment: You can tweak with `-quality` flag to increase or decrease the resulting PDF file size.
Example: `convert -quality 50 image1.jpeg image2.jpeg image3.jpeg outputFileName.pdf`

Comment: Be aware that convert uses ghostscript under the hood and gs will decode and reencode JPEGs which result in a loss of quality, even if speciiy a high quality.

Comment: I had to create more than 6000 pdfs starting from 30000 tiffs. `convert` estimate time ~6-7 hours. I used `tiffcp` and `tiff2pdf`, they took few seconds.

Comment: You can install it via `sudo apt install imagemagick`. Otherwise you don't have the convert command.

Comment: uh... wth?!  When I run convert with two png files as input and "Test.pdf" as the output, I get this error: `convert-im6.q16: not authorized \`Test.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.`

Comment: @Michael, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52661288/276052

Comment: @AlaaAli, you can take your resulting PDF and make it searchable again using my `pdf2searchablepdf` tool I wrote, [which I describe here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385947/327339). It's a wrapper around the `tesseract` OCR engine.

Comment: `convert` doesn't work for me. :( Example run: `convert *.jpg my.pdf` or `convert pg-1.jpg pg-2.jpg out.pdf`. They both produce the following error: `convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy \`PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.`

Comment: I found a solution for the `convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy \`PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.` error!: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180170/4561887

Comment: This doesn't work on text files at all. I get error: `convert-im6.q16: improper image header \`text.txt' @ error/txt.c/ReadTXTImage/450.`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1127262/1191829 checkout this link for the error (works for images)

Comment: do `<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />` in  /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
 ( https://linuxhint.com/convert-image-to-pdf-command-line/ )

Answer (score 41):

Install pdftk

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

**Pdftk**

If PDF is electronic paper, then pdftk is an electronic staple-remover, hole-punch, binder, secret-decoder-ring, and X-Ray-glasses. Pdftk is a simple tool for doing everyday things with PDF documents.

You can create pdf files from text or images with Libre Office then to stitch these togeter with other pdf files

```
pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf cat output 123.pdf
```

It can also

- Split PDF Pages into a New Document
- Rotate PDF Pages or Documents

and a lot more besides

More details here: [Ubuntu Geek: List of PDF Editing tools](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/list-of-pdf-editing-tools-for-ubuntu.html)

Comment: There is a GUI for pdftk. See my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for concatenating images with PDFs though, right?

Comment: @Garret.  No but there are several ways of converting an image to pdf, using covert for example or just print to pdf from many programs.  Once the image is a pdf then you can use pdftk to join them together.

Comment: Works like a charm and keeps the vectorial text in pdf.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be available in the default repos any more?

Comment: For newer ubuntu versions (since 18.04 I believe) use `snap install pdftk`.

Answer (score 21):

Try [PDF Chain](http://pdfchain.sourceforge.net/):

> PDF Chain is a graphical user interface for the PDF Toolkit (PDFtk). The GUI supports all common features of the command line tool in a comfortable way.

[image]

You can install it either from the default repos, or get the latest and greatest from [PDF Chain PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Epdfchain-team/+archive/ppa).

```
sudo apt-get install pdfchain
```

---

Or [PDF Mod](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/PdfMod):

> PDF Mod is a simple application for modifying PDF documents.
>
> You can reorder, rotate, and remove pages, export images from a document, edit the title, subject, author, and keywords, and combine documents via drag and drop.

```
sudo apt-get install pdfmod
```

[image]

---

See also:

- [How to copy from a pdf to another pdf in ubuntu/linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120077/how-to-copy-from-a-pdf-to-another-pdf-in-ubuntu-linux/439380#439380)

Comment: But can this concatenate text files, images and PDF files, as in the question?

Comment: You can convert the text files (say, Print to PDF) or the images (via `convert`) to PDF, and then use that.

Comment: @Garrett - just tried PDF Chain and it works to concatenate pdf files.

Answer (score 15):

For multiple files inside a directory and its subdirectories with different extensions I couldn't find a neat answer, so here it is

```
convert -quality 85 `find -type f -name '*.png' -or -name '*.jpg' | sort -V` output.pdf
```

I used [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) to pass the selected items returned by `find` command as an argument to `convert` command. Unfortunately `sort -n` didn't sort my files correctly so I tried `-V` option and it did the trick. Also make sure the name of your files and directories are in [natural sort order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) in advance. For example `dir1, dir2, dir3` not `dir1, dir_2, dir3`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Tried multiple tools all had some issue in sorting for example. Perfect!

Comment: You can install it via `sudo apt install imagemagick`. Otherwise you don't have the convert command.

Comment: Im getting error
convert-im6.q16: not authorized `./output.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.

Comment: @user1325696 i got also your error.

Comment: @SL5net See this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1081895/255257

Comment: Works great for me, the only issue I had is some files are rotated. Is it possible it removes some metadata?

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution i used to convert multiple TIFFs to PDFs.

I had to create more than 6.000 PDFs starting from 30.000 tiffs. `convert` estimate time: 6 to 7 hours.
I used `tiffcp` and `tiff2pdf`, they took few seconds.

```
$ tiffcp 1.tiff 2.tiff ... multi.tiff
$ tiff2pdf multi.tiff > final.pdf
```

This way is really fast because images are not converted, just packed.

Maybe there are some tiff formats that doesn't work so easily, for me it worked perfectly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hrm, my input tif files are 160M, but the pdf generated by tiff2pdf is about 820M. Not sure if this is really "just packing" things.

Comment: @markasoftware  - [Reduce the size of a PDF file consisting of scanned images](https://braindump.bun.ch/PDF#Reduce_the_size_of_a_PDF_file_consisting_of_scanned_images). A service menu for Dolphin file manager [here](http://cipricuslinux.blogspot.com/2022/01/shrink-pdf-reduce-pdf-size.html).

Comment: @markasoftware - In my case 90 MB multi.tiff was converted to a 365 MB pdf. Looking into it with `pdfimages -list`, under image type is listed `image`, which may mean uncompressed, with width/height `4600 /6408`. - Shrinking it to 300 dpi gave a 30 MB pdf with no sensible decrease of quality.

Answer (score 4):

Install Master PDF editor. The tool offers creating, merging and extracting PDF files. Check [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/master-pdf-editor/) for details about master PDF editor and installing it on Ubuntu

Comment: Master PDF Editor is **not** free.

Comment: @Force From [their site](http://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor.php): The Linux-based version is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: @janot Yes, but I don't think it's [free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software).

Comment: **It is free** for non-commercial purposes, works great. This is a modern, up-to-date tool, unlike others mentioned here, which are very high voted but are old and rudimentary.

Comment: https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/#get

Comment: a lot of functions are not allowed in the free version

Answer (score 2):

I use PDF-Shuffler for this kind of use, it works great.

```
sudo apt-get install pdfshuffler
```

It is a graphical tool. You simply load all the pdf files you want to fuse. You can change the page order as you wish.

Comment: Can you include instructions on how to do what the OP wants?

Comment: It is done. :-)

Comment: I would downvote, but have not enough rep. PDF-Shuffler accepts only PDF files. Question also included image files and text files.

Comment: With Libreoffice you can convert text files to pdf. As it is also possible to insert image files in Libreoffice, then convert in pdf. Once everything is in pdf, Pdf-Shuffler can do the job. But I don't think one software can do all the job at once.

Comment: As of 22.04, `pdfshuffler` (which has been renamed as "PDF Arranger") can do what the OP asked.  I needed a multi-page PDF, consisting of two `jpg` images: just dragged them into a new blank canvas in PDF Arranger, saved as new PDF and voilà...

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe nobody has mentioned latex (tex) yet. It is specifically designed for producing documents, and can combine text, images, and PDFs into a 'master' document (without any degradation of quality). It is a full suite of libraries and  an extensible markup language, basically - it's been around since forever and highly used in the scientific community, still.

Technically, it's a typesetting language.

Comment: This seems more a comment then an answer... please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Probably because nobody expected the OP's question to be about creating a day job-level work flow. Talk about using a nuke to start a camp fire! (I am a TeX fan, BTW, but I would *never* use it for this purpose.)

Comment: This is interesting. OP, could you please demonstrate it with some sample code?

Answer (score 2):

Try LaTeX with `pdflatex`.

**I had never used it before but it took me about 10 minutes to start making .PDFs with it** and about 40 minutes to get them customized exactly as I wanted. I included the best formatting guides I found, at the end.

`sudo apt-get install pdflatex && sudo apt-get install texlive`

Basically you create one `.tex` file - for example `hello.tex` - with the LaTeX language, then run `pdflatex hello.tex` on that file and it will generate the PDF. The basics of the language can be found here:
http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/

---

Here is a barebones example `.tex` file:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

 \begin{document}

 {\footnotesize
 YOUR TEXT HERE

 YOUR TEXT HERE
 }

 \end{document}
```

---

**Optional extra formatting:**

To add images: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Inserting_Images

For different font sizes: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles

For different fonts: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_typefaces

To change page size and margins when using `pdflatex`: 
`\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=148mm,paperheight=210mm,margin=5mm]{geometry}`

Answer (score 2):

Adding on the community answer above, you can do
`convert 'ls *.jpg -tr'`. To force the PDF file to have the images in chronological order.

Answer (score 2):

There is series of utilities in package `texlive-extra-utils` wrapped on `pdfjam`. To join pdfs use

```
pdfjoin -o out.pdf 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf
```

Unlike `convert` it directly manipulates on pdf without converting them to images.

Also on 18.04LTS (Bionic Beaver) at this moment package `pdftk` is not supported. I would recommend `pdfjam` if someone prefers to use command line.

Comment: The OP is asking how to convert image1.tif image 2.tif image 3.jpg to images.pdf

Comment: Not exactly. OP also wants merge pdf files with images. It is better to create pdf files from images using `img2pdf` command, since it creates pdf containing original image, and then use `pdfjoin`.

Comment: `pdftk` in 18.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/1165823/925128 (CLI only, as `pdfchain` is not available in 18.04 afaik)

Comment: `pdfjoin` will also create pdfs from images, e.g. `pdfjoin -o images.pdf *.png`

Answer (score 1):

Using [Gimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP), import as layers, export as pdf:)

*Gimp version: 2.10.8*

Comment: This is the best answer in my case because one of the images was itself a PDF that required additional processing and `convert` was unable to properly, uh, convert it. I didn't expect GIMP to handle PDFs so well. Thank you!

Comment: How is that done exactly? There is no gui option to export as pdf but the extension can be modified manually. At 260 pages as tif files it crashed though.

Comment: In the menu, under <File> there exists an option <Open as Layers> as well as one <Export as>. Version: 2.10.30

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Images to PDF

A tool I wrote called [`pdf2searchablepdf`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF) can combine many images into a single PDF. It is particularly good if you want the final PDF to have searchable text in it, as my tool performs OCR (Optical Character Recognition) on the images using a program called `tesseract` in order to bundle them into a single PDF.

Installation instructions are here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF#install

Since `pdf2searchablepdf` is a wrapper around `tesseract`, it accepts any image format supported by tesseract, which includes **bmp, pnm, png, jfif, jpeg/jpg, and tiff**. Gif is not supported. See https://coptr.digipres.org/index.php/Tesseract-ocr:

> Any image readable by Leptonica is supported in Tesseract including BMP, PNM, PNG, JFIF, JPEG, and TIFF. GIF is not supported http://www.leptonica.com/library-overview.html.

**To convert all images into a PDF**, they need to be all in the same folder and with nothing else in that folder. So, assuming you have `img1.jpg`, `img2.jpg`, and `image3.jpg`, you could do this:

```bsh
# Create an `images` dir and move all images into it
mkdir -p images
mv *.jpg images  # use `cp` instead of `mv` to copy instead of move the images

# Now combine all of these images into 1 pdf
pdf2searchablepdf images
```

That's it! You'll now have a searchable PDF file called `images_searchable.pdf` in the directory you were in when you ran the `pdf2searchablepdf` command.

Note: to **go the opposite direction and convert a PDF file into a bunch of image files**, [I like to use `pdftoppm` as I explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085889/how-to-convert-a-pdf-into-jpg-with-commandline-in-linux/61700520#61700520).

To convert a non-searchable pdf named `input.pdf` into a searchable pdf named `input_searchable.pdf`, do:

```bsh
pdf2searchablepdf input.pdf
```

See `pdf2searchablepdf -h` for the full help menu, including options and other examples.

### 2. Text to PDF

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129029/a-light-solution-to-convert-text-to-pdf-in-linux/20129300#20129300

### 3. PDF to single PDF

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf/11280219#11280219

Comment: @nsandersen, which first step? `mkdir -p images`? `sudo apt update`? Please be more specific so I can help you. Did you follow my `pdf2searchablepdf` [installation instructions](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF#install)?

Comment: @nsandersen, yes, please open an issue here to explain in detail your OS, your steps, the problem, and to paste all output and error messages: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF/issues. We can continue to debug it there.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-page pdf:
Convert all files to pdf, then join using a pdf writer eg. pdftk, pdfill, Microsoft Print to PDF, CutePDF, etc

For single-page pdf:
Convert all files to images eg. PNG, named in sequence. Then join to one page with image converter eg. imgconv

`imgconv.exe -append *.png out2.pdf` (for vertical)
`imgconv.exe +append *.png out2.pdf` (for sideways)

if you're not on Win 10 WSL, load `ImageMagick`:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

The converter, installed as part of imagemagick converts to one pdf:

```
convert "*.{png}" -quality 100 combined.pdf
```

If you already have single page pdfs, merge them with `pdftk`:

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
```

Comment: you do know that this is askubuntu, and `exe`s aren't useful on ubuntu? ;)

Comment: Hehe thanks for feedback. I've updated answer for base installs

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on [@Veles' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1145476/934644) -

Using [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) 2.10.30 -

1. File -> Open as Layers...
2. Select all images and click Open
3. File -> Export As...
4. Edit name with extension as `.pdf`
5. Select 'Layers as pages (top layers first)'
6. Select 'Reverse the pages order'
7. Export