# How can I detect PDF policy of ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, convert-command

I maintain qr-backup, a program which makes some PDFs.

My users are encountering a bug where convert fails on PDFs. Why and how to fix it is explained here. [imagemagick - convert not allowed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127260/imagemagick-convert-not-allowed)

What's a simple, fast test I can do (for example with `convert`) to tell whether they're being hit by this policy issue? I'd like to print them a clearer error if they're on an affected OS.

Comment: Check the policy file as explained in the other answer?

Comment: To clarify, I need my program to do the check, not a person

Comment: Yes. Your program should read that line in the file and check for the value "rights=none". Are you asking for the code? Your question doesn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

Check the exit status code below (0 for no policy problem)

```
convert -size 1x1 canvas:white pdf:- >/dev/null
```

Or of this (0 indicates policy problem)

```
grep -s -q 'policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF"' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```