# Concatenate PDF file without repeating images

Tags: command-line, pdf, merge

I have a directory with multiple PDF files. Each contains the same images (very high resolution, needs to stay that way), but different text:

```
my-doc-en.pdf
my-doc-es.pdf
my-doc-de.pdf
```

I have tried concatenating the files like so:

```
pdftk my-doc-en.pdf my-doc-es.pdf my-doc-de.pdf cat output my-doc-multi.pdf
```

The output file appear to have a file size that is roughly the same as the sum of the input files' sizes. This is perfect under [other](https://askubuntu.com/q/303849/7593) [circumstances](https://askubuntu.com/q/120077/7593).

However, in my specific case, I need a way to generate an output file that (somehow) knows that each PDF contains images that are found in the others, and does not repeat them.

Does an existing tool already have this feature built in that does this?

Context: I have the `*.tex` files from which these PDFs are generated, so I could potentially figure out a way to accomplish this via that route, at the PDF generation step. However, if this is available for already output PDF files, that would be a much cleaner option.